# How can I resolve "invalid input sequence for type bytea" in a Rails migration of a pg column from text to binary (bytea)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have a Rails application with a pg database, and the type of the 'input' column in one of my tables is text. I have discovered that some of my input files aren't any particular text encoding, so they need to be treated as binary data.

Thus, I created a migration:

```
class ChangeProgramsColumnsInputOutputToBinary < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :programs, :input, 'bytea USING input::bytea'
  end
end
```

However, when I run this migration, I get:

```
-- change_column(:programs, :input, "bytea USING input::bytea")
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
```

It seems that PostgreSQL doesn't like the type-cast from the text column to bytea. But why is this? Isn't bytea general enough to represent anything contained in a text column? Why is the cast failing?

I suppose there might be some specific syntax to coax pg into performing this cast but I haven't been able to find this in the pg documentation.

-------- Update -----------

I tried this, but it is truncating the binary files:

```
change_column :programs, :input, 'bytea USING convert_to(input,\'UTF8\')'
```

Comment: Please show the offending `text` value.